# Excel - Finding Data in one Column and showing the values in the corresponding column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, iif-function

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to come up with the right formula for this...
I hope it'll be clear!

I have 2 sheets in my Excel. 
The first has Active IDs (~500 rows). 
The Second has All IDs, active & inactive with a dollar value associated to each member (~1200 rows)

What I want is for Excel to take the ID in the First Sheet with all the Active ID, find it in the 2nd sheet and return the $value.

So that when I look at Sheet 1, I see the Unique ID associated with their respective $value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a lookup function, for example Vlookup.

If your IDs are in column A, you can use

```
=vlookup(A1,'Sheet 2'!$A:$B,2,false)
```

In Words: Find the value in A1 on Sheet 2 in column A and return what is in column B (the 2nd column).

Copy down.

Comment: If this solves your problem please accept the answer as explained in the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

You also can use INDEX MATCH combination (more efficient than Vlookup)

```
= INDEX( Column_with_values , MATCH ( cell_with_Active_ID , Column_with_All_IDs )
```